# Make a grid of buttons that changes layout based on screen aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I want to make a grid of buttons that changes layout based on aspect ratio so that if it was viewed on a high but not very wide layout it would be 2 across and 8 down and on a widescreen it would be 8 across and 2 down, and in the middle would be a normal 16:9 with something around 3 by 6. Essentially, I don't want it stretching, I want it to rearrange.

How would I do this in HTML/CSS? I'm open to using a framework. They aren't my main languages (I'm doing a web interface for a python script) so please be verbose in your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all determined by screen width, rather than ratio. There are a couple of ways to handle it. Assuming this HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <button class="button" id="button1">
 <button class="button" id="button2">
...
 <button class="button" id="button18">
</div>
```

The easiest way to handle it would be to give your buttons a fixed width and let the browser deal with it.

```
.container{
 width: 100%;
}
.button{
 width: 100px;
}
```

If you want wildly different behavior at different screen sizes, you'll use breakpoints. Always design [mobile first](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

```
.container{
 width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

If you want more fine grained control, what you want is [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You can chose, with flexbox, if you want your buttons to shrink-to-fit or simply wrap to the next line.

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

If you're uncomfortable with the code,[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) is a framework built for making implementing flexbox and breakpoints very easy.